# reduce div width if sibling expands

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs side by side within a parent div - the left div will contain text, while the right div will contain an image, and on button click, the right div can expand, or reduce back to its original width.

```
<style>
.parent{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}
.left{
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.right{
  width: 38%;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  float: right;
}
</style>

<input type="submit" class="toggle_div" id="button1" value="Expand"/><br>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left">Left Content</div>
    <div class="right">Right Content</div>
</div>
```

javascript to expand/reduce the div:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    var inputValue=$("#button1").attr('value');

    if(inputValue=="Expand")
    {
        $(".right").animate({width:"60%"});
        $("#button1").attr('value','Reduce');
    }
    else if(inputValue=="Reduce")
    {
        $(".right").animate({width:"38%"});
        $("#button1").attr('value','Expand');
    }
});
```

Right now, when I increase the width of the right div, it slides underneath the left div. But what I want is for the left div to reduce in size accordingly, and take on the remaining width available within the parent, with left and right div remaining side by side.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sen3t6vk/64/)

My css is weak, and I'm guessing this is something I can do in css, without having to use javascript to resize the left div too. Suggestions appreciated as always.

Comment: so you want them to stay side by side the whole time correct?

Comment: @Haza - that's correct. The right div needs to resize on button click, the left needs to adjust accordingly so they are both always side by side.

Comment: take a look at my answer @PaulMasterson

Comment: did mine work @PaulMasterson

Answer (score 2):

Your left div just wasn't being updated with the correct size so your container was more than 100%. I've fixed it here:

```js
$("#button1").click(function(){
    var inputValue=$("#button1").attr('value');
    
    if(inputValue=="Expand")
    {
        $(".right").animate({width:"60%"});
        $(".left").animate({width:"38%"});
        $("#button1").attr('value','Reduce');
    }
    else if(inputValue=="Reduce")
    {
        $(".right").animate({width:"38%"});
        $(".left").animate({width:"60%"});
        $("#button1").attr('value','Expand');
    }
});
```

```css
.parent{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}
.left{
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right{
  width: 38%;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="toggle_div" id="button1" value="Expand"/><br>
<div class="parent">
<div class="left">Left Content</div>
<div class="right">Right Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just flagged your comment because you originally posted “here is an answer using only CSS” and after I posted my answer you edited yours to include my answer. Your goal should be to help people on here; not try to gain points maliciously.

Comment: @bezierer - this seems to be the smoothest solution so far, and was the direction I would have gone in myself. I just thought that with the correct CSS, there might be a way for the left div to automatically adjust its size with respect to the right div, without also having to adjust the size of the left div through javascript. 

Thanks for the example though - it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

not really good myself, but maybe something like `http://jsfiddle.net/fd9pos8m/` ? not smooth though

```
<div style="padding:2px; width:500px; background: #FFFFFF ">
    <div class="left" style="float:left; width:50%; background: #ff0000 ">Left Content</div>
    <div class="right" style="margin-left:52%; width:38%; background: #000000 ">Right</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <input type="button" id="button1" value="expand">
</div>
<script>
$('#button1').click(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            if(val == 'expand') {
                $('.right').animate({width:'60%'});
                $(this).val('reduce');
            } else {
                $('.right').animate({width:'38%'});
                $(this).val('expand');
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: it does some kind of jump down thing

Comment: but it is not my decision it is @PaulMasterson if it works or if he likes it

Comment: @Beeto - thank you for your suggestion. As Haza mentioned, the right div jumps down, and goes outside the bounds of the parent container. But it's a good starting point though.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/CFNUJ/917/ the `#right-bg {` is staying to the `#left-bg`

the first is using just css

Comment: I tested this, and the right div seems to engulf the left, unless I am doing something wrong. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

How about using css flexbox? You don't have to worry about that .left or .right jumps down when there's no enough space for them, it just handles that situation for you.

Do remember to check the browser support for flexbox though.

I only tweaked the css:

```
.parent{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
}
.left{
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right{
  width: 38%;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sen3t6vk/74/